# to find the maximum value of a function f(x)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I tried to solve an example for IB math and I saw very interesting thing that to solve that problem they uses this kind of hypothesis :

> $$\text{If} \space \space g(x) = f(x)^n \quad \text{and} \quad g(x)  \space \space \text{is} \space \space max/min \space \space \text{at} \space \space x=x_0, \space \space \text{then} \space \space f(x)_{max}= \sqrt[n]{g(x_0)}  $$

Is this statement true ?

[Link to the image of the statement here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VraPc.jpg)

Comment: @Rebellos Under what conditions is this theorem true?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider $f(x)=x$ and $n=2$.

Comment: $g(x)=x^2$ has a minimum in $x_0=0$ and $f(x)=x$ has no minimum or maximum, so this is a good counterexample! I am right?

Comment: Yes. Do you understand what is behind this counterexample?